# Angular 2: scroll event not firing

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular 2. Trying to make rest call using scroll event. I have 200 records where initially I will make a rest call like this

```
localhost:8080/myapp/records=items&offset=0&limit=50
```

It will fetch 50 records first. But, when I scroll down it has to make another API call for fetching another 50 records like

```
localhost:8080/myapp/records=items&offset=50&limit=50
```

I tried this, but not firing the event.

**HTML**

```
    <div>
    <table class="doc-table" (scrolled)="onScroll($event.value)">
        <thead>
            <th class="avatar-th"></th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="routeTo(item.id)">
                <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.price}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
```

**Script**

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'item-cmp',
  templateUrl: 'items.component.html'
})
export class PatientsComponent(){
  onScroll(event:any){
    alert("Scolled...");
  }
}
```

Bases on offset I have to make API call. Help me, how to do this?

Answer (score 19):

I just came across this, looking for a way to tell Angular that I want the scroll (**wheel**) event to be passive (not possible yet - [#8866](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8866)). But the key word here for your question is **wheel**.

This is a pretty old question, probably you've already solved it, but there is no answer posted so those who come across this, having the same problem, will not get their answer.

Here it is:

There is no `scrolled` event.

As for the `scroll` event: it can't simply be delegated to just any element. You can attach it to `window` or `document`, but **not** to your `div`.

What you're looking for is the `wheel` event:

```
<div (wheel)="onMouseWheel($event)"></div>
```

Then you can simply check what the event provides in your component:

```
onMouseWheel(evt) {
    console.log('Wheel event: ', evt);
}
```

So you know what to use... For example the "distance" scrolled and the direction can be known from `evt.deltaX`, `evt.deltaY`. If `deltaX` is positive, then you've scrolled horizontally (on the X axis) to the right. If it's negative, then you've scrolled to the left. You get the point.

**P.S.** And don't worry, even though it's called `wheel`, it also fires when using the touchpad. I probably should have named my method simply `onWheel`.

**P.P.S.** I see another answer, suggesting `mousewheel`. `mousewheel` was never standard and is deprecated - [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel)

I suggest using `wheel`.

Comment: Please don't rely on `wheel` in the way you would have on `scroll`.

Taken from the MDN link above:

`Don't confuse the wheel event with the scroll event. The default action of a wheel event is implementation-specific, and doesn't necessarily dispatch a scroll event`.

Comment: @ServerKhalilov unfortunately, I couldn't find any other way. Note that this was about catching "scroll" on a `table` (or `div` etc.), to which you can't attach a scroll event listener. Or, at least, you couldn't at the time of writing this (as far as I could find)... I haven't looked into it again any time recently, because I haven't ran into any situations that might have any issues so far with using `(wheel)`. I guess as long as you're careful...  
But thanks for the tip! Might save some headache for some people that might run into some unexpected behaviors.

Comment: The main issue I see with "wheel" is that it doesn't work when you scroll the window with arrows.

Comment: Nor does it work with dragging the scrollbar. As far as detecting actual "scroll" events, it really doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue before and the solution was to create a directive with a host listener decorator.

```
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event']) public scrolled($event: Event) {
    this.elementScrollEvent($event);
}
```

and for window events

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) public 
    windowScrolled($event: Event) {
    this.windowScrollEvent($event);
}
```

in any case, i have also published an NPM module to detect scroll events and to find out if the user is approaching the bottom of the element to load the next page or not.

check https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-scroll-event

Comment: @NNR Please let me know if this answer worked fine with you.

Answer (score 0):

`mousewheel` event will handle the scrolling.

HTML

```
<div style="height:1000px" (mousewheel)="mousewheel($event)">

</div>
```

Typescript

```
mousewheel(event){
    console.log(event)
  }
```

You can create a custom directive and handle it as well,

```
 @HostListener('mousewheel', ['$event']) onMousewheel(event) {
           do something
 }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/WbCgHoqkLSvfjPkQYCGt?p=preview)**

Comment: its working on web platform but not working on mobile device

Answer (score -1):

There is no `scrolled` event.

I assume it should be

```
<table class="doc-table" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
```

except when `scrolled` is some custom event of yours.

Comment: Hard to tell from here, perhaps table isn't the element that emits the scroll events.

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly. What is `$event.value` supposed to do. As far as I know `event` doesn't have a `value` property.

Comment: What I am exactly trying to do is, when I scroll down to 50th record it has to make a call to API for fetching another 50 records.

Comment: Can you create a Plunker? Seems to be a pretty simple use case. If `(scroll)="onScroll($event)"` doesn't work, then I'm pretty sure there is no `scroll` event fired from this element.

Comment: Sorry to arrive late to the talk but it's the container object that is doing the scolling.  Probably your router.  Put the scroll handling there and it works fine.